# login/signup form with local storage javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm new to coding, especially with javascript, and I'm trying to make a Login/signup form in JavaScript. I'm storing the user's data via localStorage and got this far with hours and hours of googling and watching youtube videos and I would love some help here.
How can I retrieve data from local storage to be able to sign in

Sorry, my code probably looks like a mess.

Here's my HTML

```
<div class="login-form-container" id="container">
        
        <div id="close-login-btn" class="fas fa-times"></div>
        
        <form class="form" id="login">
            <h1 class="form-title">Login</h1>
            <div class="form-message form-message--error"></div>
            <div class="form-input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-input usernm" autofocus placeholder="Username or email">
                <div class="form-input-error-message"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-input-group">
                <input type="password" class="form-input pass" autofocus placeholder="Password">
                <div class="form-input-error-message"></div>
            </div>

            <button class="form-button" type="submit">Continue</button>
            <p class="form-text">
                <a href="#" class="form-link">Forgot your password?</a>
            </p>
            <p class="form-text">
                <a class="form-link" href="./" id="linkCreateAccount">Don't have an account? Create account</a>
            </p>
        </form>

        <form onsubmit="signup()" class="form form--hidden" id="createAccount">
            <h1 class="form-title">Create Account</h1>
            <div class="form-message form-message--error"></div>
            <div class="form-input-group">
                <input type="text" class="username form-input" id="username" autofocus placeholder="Username">
                <div class="form-input-error-message"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-input email" id="email" autofocus placeholder="Email Address">
                <div class="form-input-error-message"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-input-group">
                <input type="password" class="form-input password" id="password" autofocus placeholder="Password">
                <div class="form-input-error-message"></div>
            </div>

            <button class="form-button" type="submit">Continue</button>
            <p class="form-text">
                <a class="form-link" href="./" id="linkLogin">Already have an account? Sign in</a>
            </p>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Here's my JS

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const loginForm = document.querySelector("#login");
  const createAccountForm = document.querySelector("#createAccount");

  document.querySelector("#linkCreateAccount").addEventListener("click", e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    loginForm.classList.add("form--hidden");
    createAccountForm.classList.remove("form--hidden");
  });

  document.querySelector("#linkLogin").addEventListener("click", e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    loginForm.classList.remove("form--hidden");
    createAccountForm.classList.add("form--hidden");
  });

  loginForm.addEventListener("submit", e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    var myData
  });
});

// Signup function
function signup(e) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // console.log('working');

  var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
  var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
  var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

  var user = {
    email: email,
    username: username,
    password: password,
  };

  // storing input from register-form
  var json =  JSON.stringify(user);
  localStorage.setItem(username, json);
  console.log("USER ADDED");
}
```

Comment: Storing this information in localStorage isn't secure. I would look into a SERVER side method.

Comment: I know, it's just for me.

Comment: Even if this is just for you, just for practice, you should _still_ read [this article on password hashing](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm) for your own knowledge. For instance, cannelle28's answer violates the guideline "never tell the user if it was the username or password they got wrong"

Answer (score 0):

When creating new account you can use local storage like this:

```
var user = {
    email: email,
    username: username,
    password: password,
};

localStorage.setItem(userName, JSON.stringify(user));
```

While logging in, in log in form, you can check if value exists and retrieve the saved value like this:

```
var username = document.getElementById("username").value; // username of user you want to log in as

var userFromLocalStorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(username));

if(!userFromLocalStorage){
    console.log('user doesnt exist');
}

var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

if (userFromLocalStorage.password !== password){
    console.log('wrong password');
}

console.log('logged in successfully');
```

Comment: hey there! thanks for the help, Im getting this error when i try to login

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'password')
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous>

Comment: @danielali - _on which line_ did you get that error? The error message is meaningless without context. Was it `document.getElementById("password").value;`? If so that just means that `getElementById("password")` didn't find the element with an `id` of "password"